# Prometheus does not show metrics of all pods

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, production

When we use Kubernetes for production and we have a scaled application with many pods and publish as a service, every single metrics fetching request of Prometheus is routed to a pod with a random of selection.
In this situation, results are not true for monitoring.

In a moment we need all pods metrics (for example 10 pod) and it's not possible by calling a Kubernetes Service endpoint! 
Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your `kubernetes_sd_configs` so it scrapes the pods individually and not just the service.
To do that, set the `role` to `pod`, like this:

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
```

[See this blog post](https://stuff.21zoo.com/posts/prometheus-kubernetes-configure-scrape-pods/) for a full config example.

Comment: what was happening in this mode? Kubernetes network routes request randomly to pods on each Prometheus request! we need all pod metric at a time
is it possible?

Comment: When the role is `service` then the prometheus scrape requests will go round robin to a random pod but when it is `pod` each pod will get scraped individually.